# Using require('angular') in node gives Window is not Defined

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

So I am completely new to node but I figured out how to install node_modules. What I am trying to figure out is how to properly include 'Angular' into my code.

So from a new express 4 spin up I did:

```
npm install --save angular
```

Then I went into `routes/index.js` and added the `require('angular')`:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
require('angular');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

But when I do node start I get an error that says:

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/al/Projects/node/podcastsearch/podcast/node_modules/angular/angular.js:26307:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/al/Projects/node/podcastsearch/podcast/node_modules/angular/index.js:1:63)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
```

What is the proper way to include angular?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Angular is client slide script library. Node JS require loads node modules and Angular is not a Node module.

In your HTML page you should do something like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Angular App!</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="flapperNews" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div>
      {{test}}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Update:
Based on comment. Angular module - https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular

Fetches angular js files for you and saves them in node modules folders. Angular still remains a client side library and you need to add a script tag in your HTML to use angular. You should not require it in node code. Please check the samples given in that link as well.

Else you can think of using require js, head js, browserify etc. on client side

Comment: I read the angular npm page https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular and it said I could include it via the scripts or require('angular'). I am fully aware that angular is client side. I am curious why the module page says it can be used via a require()

Comment: @allencoded You can use `require()` in your client-side scripts by using Browserify for similar.

Comment: Ah thanks brad that clears it right up. I knew angular was a client side library just didn't know enough about require() I suppose. I did know I could just include it by going node_modules/angular/angular.js in my html but wanted to do the spiffy require()

Answer (score 2):

Update for @`AnujYadav`'s answer using webpack version 3.4.1:

Install angular:

```
npm install angular --save-dev
```

Config (in `webpack.config.js` file):

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        angular: path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/angular/angular')
    },
    output: {
        ...
    },
    module: {
        ...
    }
};
```

In the html page:

```
<script src="/{your_path}/angular.js"></script>
<script>
    // you can use 'angular' now    
</script>
```